# Backwards comparability of SharePoint Online (version 16) DLL's

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I currently have a provider hosted app that has been built around the SharePoint Online platform and therefore uses version 16 DLL's for SharePoint.  I have a need to deploy this app to a SharePoint 2013 Foundation (on-premises) installation but the version of the DDL's are being stated as the wrong version by Visual Studio on the deployment (as SharePoint 2013 Foundation required version 15 of the DLL's).

Is it possible to use the SharePoint Online DLL's with an on-premises version of SharePoint 2013 (i.e. in some kind of backwards compatibility option) or is there a quick/efficient method of converting the app to work on-premises with SharePoint 2013 without re-writing the app from scratch?

Any help or suggestions available will be much appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: If your server is properly patched there should be a version 16 of the Client dll on the server itself: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI`

Comment: At which point did the on-premises version of SharePoint 2013 Foundation get these Client DLL's please?  I will then ensure the server is patched up to that level at least...

Comment: I'm not sure, but is has been there (I think) for at least a year, but in the latest patches (like march or april this year) I think it got the latest version of the 16 dll with some new API:s

Comment: Thanks Robert, I will get a test environment upgraded and see if that provides what is needed to resolve the issue...